# Bash remove duplicates entries in column

Tags: bash

I'm looking to delete duplicate date in the 1st column, and just keep the first.

from:

```
Date          Time     cnt
01/03/2015  18:02:06    0
01/03/2015  18:03:07    0
01/03/2015  18:04:07    0
02/03/2015  18:02:07    0
02/03/2015  18:03:07    0
02/03/2015  18:04:07    0
02/03/2015  18:05:08    0
02/03/2015  18:06:06    0
03/03/2015  18:02:06    0
03/03/2015  18:03:06    0
03/03/2015  18:04:07    0
03/03/2015  18:05:07    0
03/03/2015  18:06:07    0
```

to:

```
Date          Time     cnt
01/03/2015  18:02:06    0
            18:03:07    0
            18:04:07    0
            18:05:07    0
            18:06:07    0
02/03/2015  18:02:07    0
            18:03:07    0
            18:04:07    0
            18:05:08    0
            18:06:06    0
03/03/2015  18:02:06    0
            18:03:06    0
            18:04:07    0
            18:05:07    0
            18:06:07    0
```

Many tks for help

Comment: Is the input data tab-separated, or a fixed width format? Is it necessary to preserve the spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a ruby one-liner:

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{ h={} }; items = $_.partition(" "); items[0] = h[items[0]] ? " "*items[0].size : items[0];  puts items.join(); h[items[0]] = true '
```

Answer (score 3):

With **awk**:

```
awk '{if(a[$1]++){printf("\t    %s\t%s\n", $2, $3)}else{print}}' File
```

For every `column1` value encountered for the first time(`i.e a[$1] = 0`), print the line as it is(done by the else part). For duplicate `column1` values, do not print the first column(Tab Formatting for indentation).

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ awk '{if(a[$1]++){printf("\t    %s\t%s\n", $2, $3)}else{print}}' ff
Date          Time     cnt
01/03/2015  18:02:06    0
            18:03:07    0
            18:04:07    0
02/03/2015  18:02:07    0
            18:03:07    0
            18:04:07    0
            18:05:08    0
            18:06:06    0
03/03/2015  18:02:06    0
            18:03:06    0
            18:04:07    0
            18:05:07    0
            18:06:07    0
```

Comment: Shorter version `awk 'a[$1]++{$0=sprintf("\t    %s\t%s", $2, $3)}1'`

Answer (score 0):

This is untested and not bash, but you could use perl for this.

Split each line into date, time, count.

Check a hash to see if you've seen this date before.

If no, print date, time, count.

If yes, print tab, time, count.

```
use strict;
my $hash;
while(<>){
chomp;
my ($date, $time, $count)= split; 
if (defined($hash{$date})){
    print "\t\t$time\t$count\n";
}
else{
    print "$date\t$time\t$count\n";
    $hash{$date}=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answers!

Perl, Bash, Awk work well, but Ruby is more flexible, because, in fact, there are 20 columns after... ^^